# How is R.java generated in Android?

Tags: android, xml

I would like to know how the R.java file in Android is generated. Are the fields calculated with some algorithm, and is there any degree of randomness, or would res/raw/foo always be the same regardless what app is using it (like MD5/ hashing algorithms)?

What brought this up is checking the AdMob Jar provided by Google. It contains its own R.java, and allows for custom XML attributes on custom views, but without the need to include an attrs.xml/ styleable file. Any thoughts on how this is possible?

Thanks

Comment: Foolishly.  They should have called it `Resources` or some such thing.  Pretty much anything is more descriptive than `R`.  More seriously, the algorithm is not completely random, as you can regenerate your `R.java` file any number of times and still get the same identifiers for the same resources.

Comment: That is helpful to know, but I would like to know precisely how the integers are calculated. Moreover, how can I not require that a resource actually be included but I can use custom attributes?